# close any open flyout/dropdown when another is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these two flyout menus they toggle in and out and up and down respectfully. When they are out the occupy the same space overlapping on each other. It doesn't look that bad but it would be better if the open menu closed when the other was clicked open. It's possible in the future that there will be more than two menus. So I need a solution that when you open a menu it simultaneously closes any open menus. I suppose they would need a class that relates them. I'm unclear on how to close other open menus with out also closing the one that I am trying to open at that moment. Hope that makes sense.

```
showFooWindow = function() {
$('.channels-sessions-tab').click(function(){
    var $CSpane = $('.current-foo');

    var paneState = parseInt($CSpane.css('left'),10) == 0 ? -$CSpane.outerWidth()-11 : 0

    $CSpane.animate({
        left: paneState
    }, {
        duration: 700,
        specialEasing: {
            width: 'linear',
            height: 'easeOutBounce'
        }});
});
};

showBarWindow = function() {
$('.channel-session-tab').click(function(){
    var $CSpane = $('.current-bar');

    var paneState = parseInt($CSpane.css('top'),10) == 0 ? -$CSpane.outerHeight()-11 : 0

    $CSpane.animate({
        top: paneState
    }, {
        duration: 600,
        specialEasing: {
            width: 'linear',
            height: 'easeOutBounce'
        }});
});
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ultimately what I came up with. It would be cool to come up with a clever way to abstract flowOuRight and flownOutDown. If I did then I could remove a few lines of code.

```
showFoo = function() {
$('.foo-tab').click(function(){
    var duration = 700;
    var element = $('.foo');
    var direction = {left: parseInt(element.css('left'),10) == 0 ? -element.outerWidth()-11 : 0};
    closeOtherFlyouts();
    element.addClass("flownOutRight");
    flyoutAnimate(direction, duration, element);
});
};

showBar = function() {
$('.bar-tab').click(function(){
    var duration = 600;
    var element = $('.bar');
    var direction = {top: parseInt(element.css('top'),10) == 0 ? -element.outerHeight()-11 : 0};
    closeOtherFlyouts();
    element.addClass("flownOutDown");
    flyoutAnimate(direction, duration, element);
});
};

closeOtherFlyouts = function() {
if ($('.flownOutDown')) {
    var duration = 600;
    var element = $('.flownOutDown');
    var direction = {top: -element.outerHeight()-11};
    flyoutAnimate(direction, duration, element);
    element.removeClass("flownOutDown");
}

if ($('.flownOutRight')) {
    var duration = 700;
    var element = $('.flownOutRight');
    var direction = {left: -element.outerWidth()-11} ;
    flyoutAnimate(direction, duration, element);
    element.removeClass("flownOutRight");
}
};

flyoutAnimate = function(direction, duration, element) {
element.animate(
    direction,
    {
        duration: duration,
        specialEasing: {
            width: 'linear',
            height: 'easeOutBounce'
        }});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like this:

```
$(".flownOut")./*close your flyouts*/.removeClass(".flownOut");
$CSpane.addClass("flownOut");
$CSpane.animate({
        left: paneState
    }, { .... the rest of your code
```